# How to split specific string in site Url?

Tags: c#, split

I have a url like this:

> http://ycchoi/sites/dev/Lists/List/AllItems.aspx

And I want to split it like this:

> Lists/List/AllItems.aspx

How can I do that?

Comment: Does `url.Replace("http://ycchoi/sites/dev/", "");` do the job?

Comment: Is it for this particular example? how the input format should be

Comment: You do this with only this domain or do you have difference difference domain names?

Comment: Is ("http://ycchoi/sites/dev/") is your website base URL.

Comment: Hi @RydenChoi did you have a look at the solution provided by me. If you still face any issue please acknowledge. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick for you.

```
string ddr = "http://ycchoi/sites/dev/Lists/List/AllItems.aspx";
string[] ddrs = ddr.Split('/').Skip(Math.Max(0, ddr.Split('/').Count() - 3)).ToArray();
string ExpectedURL = String.Join("/", ddrs);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per `Diligent Key Presser's` comment : You can do this using following code...

```
url = "http://ycchoi/sites/dev/Lists/List/AllItems.aspx";
string newParth = url.Replace("http://ycchoi/sites/dev/" , "");
```